# Receiving the following error on joomla install

Tags: joomla

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Comment: so it looks like it is installed can create a menu item to the civicrm dashboard but if I try to launch it I get the following errors

Comment: Warning: include_once(/home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php on line 9

Comment: Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php on line 9

Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php on line 33

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/dsitver/public_html/grotonsportsmen.com/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php on line 33

Comment: See this article https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/joomla-pc/ proper installation steps